# Find End Date If We Have Start Date and Interval . Excluding custom holiday list and weekends . In Python(Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django, numpy, date, python-datetime

So, What I am trying to achieve is.

```
start_date = "2020-07-16"
number_of_days = 15
holidays = ["2020-07-19",2020-07-21]
```

Now I Want to calculate the end date i.e 16 Aug + 15 days excluding all custom holidays which I give in the list and all the weekend's(Sundays+Saturdays).

Any suggestions on how could I achieve it. The solution I found till now is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502797/python-django-count-business-days) using NumPy but it doesn't fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
total_days = number_of_days
for i in number_of_days:
    current_day = start_data + timedelta(days=i)
    if current_day in holidays:
        total_days += 1
    elif current_day.isoweekday() in [6, 7]:
        total_days += 1
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days= total_days)
```

I hope that this can at least get close to the answer you want, Im not sure aboyt the exact syntax as I am currently on a phone.

But looking at the NumPy answer, what exactly doesn't it fill in your requirements?

Comment: Thankyou man it worked , that example is to find out the number of days in between excluding holidays and weekends. but I want to achieve the last date using an interval.